ldap_add: No such attribute (16) additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090FB4, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839
I want to add a new user to my ldap mail server backend (iredmail to be precise).
I have configured my LDIF file which is as follows.
dn: mail=john@mydomain.com,ou=Users,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: mailUser
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: amavisAccount
mail: john@mydomain.com
userPassword: {SSHA512}tT1LNNZH71LQ2teegGLuuhIRPan1C+DaJ7WgNV4jZnRphlUQFCvQv
 G8mONAkcro0qQ4SUZX+z3/oyGTaNPrmiNQjbE8=
mailQuota: 0
cn: John Scott
sn: John
uid: John
storageBaseDirectory: /var/vmail
mailMessageStore: vmail1/mydomain.com/j/o/n/john-2024.03.19.23.13.47/
homeDirectory: /var/vmail/vmail1/mydomain.com/j/o/n/john-2024.03.19.23.13.4
 7/
accountStatus: active
enabledService: internal
enabledService: doveadm
enabledService: lib-storage
enabledService: indexer-worker
enabledService: dsync
enabledService: quota-status
enabledService: mail
enabledService: smtp
enabledService: smtpsecured
enabledService: smtptls
enabledService: pop3
enabledService: pop3secured
enabledService: pop3tls
enabledService: imap
enabledService: imapsecured
enabledService: imaptls
enabledService: managesieve
enabledService: managesievesecured
enabledService: managesievetls
enabledService: sieve
enabledService: sievesecured
enabledService: sievetls
enabledService: deliver
enabledService: lda
enabledService: lmtp
enabledService: forward
enabledService: senderbcc
enabledService: recipientbcc
enabledService: sogo
enabledService: sogowebmail
enabledService: sogocalendar
enabledService: sogoactivesync
enabledService: shadowaddress
enabledService: displayedInGlobalAddressBook
shadowLastChange: 19832
amavisLocal: TRUE

When I run the following command -
ldapadd -x -D myaccount@mydomain.com -W -f newuser.ldif
I get the following error:
**adding new entry "mail=john@mydomain.com,ou=Users,domainName=mydomain.com,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090FB4, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839**

I can't figure out which attribute is missing. Has anyone experienced this before.
I have enabled debug on ldapadd command ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP x.x.x.x:389
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying x.x.x.x:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect: 
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({i) ber:
ber_flush2: 40 bytes to sd 4
ldap_result ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x5d596c002de0 Connections:
* host: xxx.xxx.xx  port: 389  (default)
* from: IP=x.x.x.x:8028
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Thu Apr 25 17:18:06 2024


** ld 0x5d596c002de0 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x5d596c002de0 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x5d596c002de0 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x5d596c002de0 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x5d596c002de0 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 16 contents:
ldap_find_request_by_msgid: msgid 1, lr 0x5d596c003b80 lr->lr_refcnt = 1
read1msg: ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 1 message type bind
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
read1msg: ld 0x5d596c002de0 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 1
request done: ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 1
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_return_request: lrx 0x5d596c003b80, lr 0x5d596c003b80
ldap_return_request: lrx->lr_msgid 1, lrx->lr_refcnt is now 0, lr is still present
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_free_request_int: lr 0x5d596c003b80 msgid 1 removed
ldap_do_free_request: asked to free lr 0x5d596c003b80 msgid 1 refcnt 0
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_msgfree
adding new entry "mail=john@xxx.xxx.xxx,ou=Users,domainName=xxx.xxx.xxx,o=domains,dc=x,dc=x,dc=x"
ldap_add_ext
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
ber_flush2: 1003 bytes to sd 4
ldap_result ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 2
wait4msg ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 2 (timeout 100000 usec)
wait4msg continue ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 2 all 1
** ld 0x5d596c002de0 Connections:
* host: xxx.xxx.xxx  port: 389  (default)
* from: IP=15.10.5.8:2134
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Thu Apr 25 17:18:06 2024


** ld 0x5d596c002de0 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x5d596c002de0 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x5d596c002de0 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x5d596c002de0 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 2 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x5d596c002de0 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 2 all 1
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 114 contents:
ldap_find_request_by_msgid: msgid 2, lr 0x5d596bffff60 lr->lr_refcnt = 1
read1msg: ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 2 message type add
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
read1msg: ld 0x5d596c002de0 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 2
request done: ld 0x5d596c002de0 msgid 2
res_errno: 16, res_error: <00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090FB4, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839>, res_matched: <>
ldap_return_request: lrx 0x5d596bffff60, lr 0x5d596bffff60
ldap_return_request: lrx->lr_msgid 2, lrx->lr_refcnt is now 0, lr is still present
ldap_free_request (origid 2, msgid 2)
ldap_free_request_int: lr 0x5d596bffff60 msgid 2 removed
ldap_do_free_request: asked to free lr 0x5d596bffff60 msgid 2 refcnt 0
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_msgfree
ldap_err2string
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
    additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090FB4, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839


You’ll have to find the schema or perhaps an existing entry and go through your attributes against it.
